# python calling a def() inside of def()

Tags: python, function

I'm making a package for my python assistant and have found a problem.

Im importing the following program into the main script.

```
import os

def load() :
    def tts(name) :
        os.system("""PowerShell -Command "Add-Type –AssemblyName System.Speech; (New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer).Speak(' """ + name + " ');"
```

how do i call the function into my program

ive tried :

```
import loadfile
loadfile.load().tts("petar")
```

and it didn't work

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: The function `tts` will stop to exist once `load` is completed. So you can not simply call it from the outside.

Comment: `name` is undefined, so the function would fail even you managed to call it.

Comment: This sounds like it may be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You're asking for help with a specific issue with nested functions, but you haven't explained enough about what you're actually trying to achieve for us to answer you. Without the context that led you to think that nested functions would be a good solution, the whole question seems silly. The real answer may be "nested functions are not a suitable solution for your problem".

Comment: Blckknght in my program I wanted to add multiple Def() inside of the load() to load different features

Comment: I got a badge on this question!, but this is the one that made me quit asking/answering SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are never supposed to expose a sub-function outside of its scope, in this case, the `tts` method outside `load`. It's actually imposible to access `tts` without exposing its reference outside of your `load()` method.  I suggest you to rather use a class like this:

In `loadfile.py`:

```
import os

class LoadFile(object):
    def tts(self, name):
        os.system("""PowerShell -Command "Add-Type –AssemblyName System.Speech; (New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer).Speak(' """ + name + " ');")

def load():
    return LoadFile()
```

On main code:

`import loadfile
loadfile.load().tts("petar")`

Answer (score 1):

When you run `loadfile.load().tts("petar")`, it is equivalent to:

```
v = loadfile.load()
v.tts("petar")
```

Your method `loadfile.load()` does not return any value, so `v` is assigned `None`. Then you try to call `tts()` against `None`, which is an error.

Why are you trying to do this? Maybe you want to create a class?

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this code to call def within def

```
def num1(x):
   def num2(y):
      return x * y
   return num2
res = num1(10)

print(res(5))
```

[Reference URL](https://stackabuse.com/python-nested-functions/)

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the decorator "@classmethod" to create some funcion inside your class that doesn't need create an instance of your class.

In your "my_package.py" file you can do some like this:

```
class Loaders():

   @classmethod
   def load(self, parameter):
      return self.tts(parameter)

   def tts(self):
      os.system("""PowerShell...""")
      ...
      return self
```

In python files that will call this "my_package.py" you can code:

```
       filename        classname
          |                |
          V                V
from my_package import Loaders

# to use your method tts you can Instantiate your class and after call the method:
x = Loaders()
x.tts('petar')

# or you can call directly some classmethod
x = Loaders.load('petar')
```

If you need change the steps when initializing your class, ... you can edit the instantiation method **init**

```
class Loaders():

   def __init__(self, some_param):
      ...do something...

      return self

...
# so when you when you call 
x = Loaders()

# " ... do something ..." will do and the class object (self) will return.
```